# Strange double destructor call when using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, destructor, shared-ptr

Finally I tracked down very strange bug, which is caused by double calling destructor. Here is the minimal code that reproduces the bug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>

class cEventSystem {
    public:
        cEventSystem() {
            std::cout << "constructor: " << this << std::endl;
        }
        ~cEventSystem() {
            std::cout << "destructor: " << this << std::endl;
        }
};

class cSubscriber {
    public:
        cSubscriber(cEventSystem& eventSystem) : eventSystem(eventSystem) {}
        virtual ~cSubscriber() {}
        virtual void onEvent() = 0;
    protected:
        cEventSystem& eventSystem;
};

class cTileBrowser: public cSubscriber {
    public:
        cTileBrowser(cEventSystem eventSystem) : cSubscriber(eventSystem) {}
        void onEvent() {}
};

class cGui: public cSubscriber {
    public:
        cGui(cEventSystem& eventSystem) : cSubscriber(eventSystem) {
            tileBrowser = std::make_shared<cTileBrowser>(eventSystem);
        }
        void onEvent() {}
        std::shared_ptr<cTileBrowser> tileBrowser;
};

int main() {
    cEventSystem eventSystem;
    cGui gui(eventSystem);
}
```

The output is:

```
 constructor: 0x7fffffffe67f
 destructor: 0x7fffffffe2df
 destructor: 0x7fffffffe67f
```

As you can see the first destructor is unwanted and it is called on different object which wasn't constructed at all (the adress is different), but in my real code the adress is close enough and it corrupts the containers I have in event system.

Debugging shows that it is make_shared which causes that destructor call.

What causes that unwanted destructor call and how can I get rid of it?
I use g++4.7 with c++11 flag.

The problem is that the unwanted destructor call *usually* (90% of times) corrupts my event system containers in my real code which causes segfaults, but rarely it doesn't corrupt it and everything works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The CTileBrowser constructor is taking its argument by value.  You're likely seeing the destruction of a temporary copy created for that constructor.  Change it to a reference parameter and I bet the problem will go away.

Comment: man, you are a hero, it works in my real code now! But why temporary copy is so unsafe that it can corrupt my data in memory? I almost always pass by reference (this one was a mistake), but it seems at least strange to me.

Comment: @user1873947, since the copy constructor is compiler generated it's probably doing the wrong thing. If it makes a copy of a pointer for example and the destructor then deletes it, you're left with a dangling pointer in the original object.

Comment: @Mark Ransom that's it. In my real code I have a set of pointers.

Comment: Thank you all, the problem is solved. I will accept when it is possible.